# querying data from aggregation on rank basis mongodb python

Tags: python, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am trying to query data on ranking basis based on marks of subject

here is my document

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a620a1b0856ed736ffe1163"),
    "name" : "saif",
    "science" : 25,
    "roll no" : 10,
    "maths" : 89,
    "class" : 1,
    "history" : 14
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a620a3f0856ed78ff23a5f7"),
    "name" : "john",
    "science" : 62,
    "roll no" : 18,
    "maths" : 69,
    "class" : 1,
    "history" : 28
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a620a630856ed7ec14b8cd9"),
    "name" : "peter",
    "science" : 22,
    "roll no" : 8,
    "maths" : 59,
    "class" : 1,
    "history" : 58
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a620aa90856ed0ce5c4432d"),
    "name" : "zarar",
    "science" : 22,
    "roll no" : 15,
    "maths" : 29,
    "class" : 4,
    "history" : 58
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a620ac10856ed10b8f5af4a"),
    "name" : "abir",
    "science" : 22,
    "roll no" : 24,
    "maths" : 23,
    "class" : 9,
    "history" : 58
}
```

i can get the list of data on ranking basis with this code

```
from pymongo import MongoClient # import mongo client to connect  
from bson.son import SON
import pprint  
# Creating instance of mongoclient  
client = MongoClient()  
# Creating database  
db = client.school  

# Creating document  
candidates = db.candidates  
# Inserting data 

mathpipeline=[
  { "$sort": { "class" : 1,"maths" : -1} },   
   { "$group": {
    "_id": "$class",

    "items": { "$push": "$$ROOT" }
  }},
  { "$unwind": { "path": "$items", "includeArrayIndex": "items.rank", } },

  { "$project": { 
    "_id": 0, 
    "name":"$items.name",
    "class": "$items.class", 
    "maths": "$items.maths",
    "rank": { "$add": [ "$items.rank",1] } 
  }},
  { "$sort": { "class" : 1,"maths" : -1}}
]

# Fetching data  
data=list(db.candidates.aggregate(mathpipeline) 

pprint.pprint(data)
```

In Output i can get the list on ranking basis

```
[{u'class': 1, u'maths': 89, u'name': u'saif', u'rank': 1L},
 {u'class': 1, u'maths': 69, u'name': u'john', u'rank': 2L},
 {u'class': 1, u'maths': 59, u'name': u'peter', u'rank': 3L},
 {u'class': 4, u'maths': 29, u'name': u'zarar', u'rank': 1L},
 {u'class': 9, u'maths': 23, u'name': u'abir', u'rank': 1L}]
```

but what if i want to query only one user data on the basis of roll number and class ?

i tried using `data=list(db.candidates.aggregate(mathpipeline).find_one({'class':1,'roll no':10},{'name':1,'maths':1 }))`but no luck.any help is much appreciated

my expected output is single dictionary if i want to query data from roll number and class for eg in case of john roll number is 18 and class is 1

so my output will be like

```
{u'class': 1, u'maths': 69, u'name': u'john', u'rank': 2L}
```

Regards Saif

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: @Saravana for eg if i want to query the data from john i will suplly roll no and class so i will be getting single output like

`{u'class': 1, u'maths': 69, u'name': u'john', u'rank': 2L}`

Comment: on the aggregated result you want filter by name, roll no and class?

Comment: @Saravana that's what I exactly want

Comment: you can simply iterate the array and match the criteria

Comment: An example is much appreciated I had never used cursor as I am new to mongo db